# Are there exceptions that aren't caught by general E : Exception?

Tags: delphi, exception

I was wondering if there are exceptions/errors, which do make your code jump into an except block but aren't handled by  E : exception.

```
 try
   i := StrToInt(s);
   {...do a lot more...}
 except
   on E : EConvertError do begin
     ShowMessage('You need to input a valid number.');
   end;
   on E : Exception do begin
     ShowMessage('Something went wrong.');
     Raise; 
   end;
 end;
```

Is there a way that a program could have an error that would ignore both statements in this except block?
Or should I do it like this :

```
 try
   i := StrToInt(s);
   {...do a lot more...}
 except
   on E : EConvertError do begin
     ShowMessage('You need to input a valid number.');
   end;
   else begin  // swapped on e : Exception with else
     ShowMessage('Something went wrong.');
     Raise; 
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: Yes, the [`OutlineError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Outline.OutlineError) is an exception which is not the [`Exception`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.Exception) descendant. But I believe that's the only exception in exceptions (which cannot be raised in this particular case).

Comment: @TLama  Would an error like that still jump into the except block?

Comment: Yes, it will. As any other object that you `raise`.

Comment: So if I want to catch "everything" I would need to use the "else" construct instead of relying on  "on E:Exception"?

Comment: Yes, you would have to use `else` for that.

Comment: No. `on E:TObject` as per my answer

Comment: @David, everything else better describes `else`.

Comment: @TLama Yes. Agreed. But doesn't let you get the exception object. Anyway, you wrote "would have to". But that's not so.

Comment: @David, d'oh, that's a typo; I meant to write *need* instead of *have*. About the exception object you are right, but OP doesn't seem to care about it.

Comment: @TLama Agreed. I think asker is perhaps over thinking this. Anyway, I tried to cover as many angles as possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can throw anything that derives from `TObject`. In order to catch every such class you'd need to specify `TObject` in your `on` statement.

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Exceptions#Declaring_Exception_Types):

> Exception types are declared just like other classes. In fact, it is possible to use an instance of any class as an exception, but it is recommended that exceptions be derived from the SysUtils.Exception class defined in SysUtils.

In reality I know of no code that throws anything that does not derive from `Exception`, although @TLama points out one example in a legacy deprecated VCL class in the comments.  Certainly `StrToInt` only throws `Exception` descendents.

If you don't need to access the exception object you can use a plain `except` clause without an `on` statement.

```
try
  ....
except 
  // deal with all exceptions
end;
```

Or you can use the `else` clause of an `on` statement as a catch all, again you won't get immediate access to the exception object.

Otherwise you can specify a base class for the exceptions that you wish to catch. For instance `on E: TObject` catches everything derived from `TObject`.

So, as we see, it is possible that things not derived from `Exception` may be thrown. But you must ask yourself if your code ever does that? If not then it makes most sense to test for `Exception` in your catch all handlers. That will give you access to the members of `Exception`. Of course, one does wonder why you have a catch all exception handler. Their existence are often indication of poor design.

Continuing the theme of `StrToInt`, you only need to catch `EConvertError`. That's what is raised when the conversion fails. You should ignore any other exception class as, in your example, the code won't know what to do with anything else. One of the goals of writing exception handling code is to handle what you know how to deal with, and ignore everything else.

In fact, `TryStrToInt` is what you need here:

```
if TryStrToInt(s, i) then
  // do stuff with i
else
  // deal with conversion error
```

This obviates the need to handle any exceptions and makes your code far more readable.

I know that `StrToInt` is just an example, but it serves quite well to demonstrate the benefits of trying to avoid handling exceptions.

Comment: the StrToInt was most only meant as an example.

Comment: And it gave me an opportunity to show how to avoid catch all exception handlers.

Comment: The situation is like this: I do some database work, start a transaction, when everything goes right I commit it, but in case there is an exception, I rollback the transaction and then reraise the error. The problem is, that whatever was going on, it got me stuck in the transaction, neither committing or rollbacking, so the table was blocked for other instances.

Comment: I don't think I can debug the scenario based on a description in the comments. I've just tried to answer the question that you asked. Please feel free to ask a new specific question with your specific scenario detailed.